# jpgraph works localhost but not on web

Tags: php, http, apache2, jpgraph, dyndns

I have made a `.php` file that produces a graph and it shows perfect when run from localhost.
When I put it in my web-folder `/var/www/"my-dyndns-web-adress.com"/web/` I get a blank page (my-dyndns-web-adress is fake instead of my real one).

From `tail -f other_vhosts_access.log` I am getting this:

```
my-dyndns-web-adress.com:80 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [01/Sep/2012:15:31:37 +0200]
  "GET /sqlex.php HTTP/1.1" 500 275 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
  (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.25 (KHTML, like Gecko)
  Version/6.0 Safari/536.25"
```

It appears to be some sort of HTTP error, but I don't know how to address that, have googled with no luck.

I have traced it to crash just when the first $graph = something shall execute. Before that there are no problems.

Comment: You should enable error reporting in your php script to see what the error is. Just put this at the top: `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`

Comment: Its a 500 internal server error, tho without seeing code or error line, its impossible to answer. could be many things.

Comment: Thanks jeroen, that was what I was looking for. Now I know what the problem is:  Warning: include(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/jpgraph/jpgraph.php) is not within the allowed path(s):

Comment: This is in the beginning of my file: <?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
include ("/usr/share/jpgraph/jpgraph.php");
include ("/usr/share/jpgraph/jpgraph_line.php"); 
So I have to look for where to allow my includes, any idea? Maybe I have to include a .htaccess file to handle that.

Comment: Now, I have installed the libraries within my web area (lib) and no errors comes as before so it finds the jpgraph libraries. But now I am getting only a little blue square with question mark from jpgraph, something is happening but no graphic.

Comment: AT LAST! Thanks for the tips, I had an echo "line 2"; in the beginning - not allowed! Now it works like charm. Have a nice day/evening/morning what suits best. Regards, Ralph in Sweden

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about where to put your included files: an `.htaccess` file will only have effect if the files are within the web-root.

I normally put my includes inside the php include directory (set in the ini file, `include_path`) if they are shared by multiple sites **or** in the project directory outside the web-root when they are for that specific project only (my project directory normally contains folders like `/sys` and `/www` where `/www` is the web-root).